# Install Semantic UI with error - at AnonymousObservable.tryCatcher (endless loop)

Tags: semantic-ui, yarnpkg

When I do yarn install, it goes well at first, until I see the following screen. And it looks like it is blocked there.

```
warning "react-easy-chart@0.1.8" has incorrect peer dependency "d3-time-format@^0.4.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[1/3] ⢀ node-sass: Binary is fine
[-/3] ⢀ waiting...
[3/3] ⢀ semantic-ui:     at AnonymousObservable.tryCatcher (C:\Repo\vcm-spa\app\node_module
[-/3] ⠠ waiting...
[-/3] ⠠ waiting...
```

I am using Yarn 0.19.1, and Semantic UI 2.2.7

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's a known bug: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/976

But if you abort it, try once more with Yarn, and then run `npm install semantic-ui --saveDev` then you get a working setup.